# How to only render children that have a certain prop in React with a HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am creating a HOC that will check its children (and theirs) on a certain prop, `onEditable` in this case. If none is specified it assumes the child wants to be showed, if it's set to `hide` it won't render the child.

(The prop is not a boolean because later on I will add more options)

```js
const MyComponent = ({ children, }) => {
  const getChildren = (myChildren, onEditable = 'show') => React.Children.map(myChildren, (child) => {
    let myOnEditable = onEditable;
    const { props, } = child;
    if (props) {
      const { onEditable: onEdit, children: grandChildren, } = props;
      onEdit && (myOnEditable = onEdit);
      typeof grandChildren === 'object'
          && getChildren(grandChildren, myOnEditable);
    }
    console.log(myOnEditable);
    if (myOnEditable === 'show') {
      return child;
    }
  });
  return <div>{getChildren(children)}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent>
      <p onEditable="show">show</p>
      Unspecified
      <div onEditable="hide">
        <span onEditable="show">show inside hide</span>
        <p>Unspecified in hide</p>
      </div>
      <div onEditable="show">
        <span onEditable="hide">hide inside show</span>
        <p>Unspecified in show</p>
      </div>
    </MyComponent>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<div id='root'/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Assigning the right `onEditable` value in cascading way works, as seens in the console, but only rendering the `show` ones doesn't. Which kind of makes senses when following along with the code. Problem is; I have no idea how to solve that.

The hardest thing for me to wrap my head around is being able to render a parent component which has `onEditable` set to `hide` when one of it's children has it set to `show`.

That might sound confusing, so I'll explain some more. A parent component with `onEditable` set to `hide` cascades this property to it's children (in the way I want my HOC), but if down the line a child or grandchild has this prop set to show, all his parents need to render as well, but *not* his siblings (because they still have the `hide` property from their parents, unless specified otherwise)

So I expect the following DOM structure in my example:

```js
<p onEditable="show">show</p>
Unspecified
<div onEditable="hide">
  <span onEditable="show">show inside hide</span>
</div>
<div onEditable="show">
  <p>Unspecified in show</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "if it's set to hide it won't render the child."

You shouldn't pass the child in if it's not supposed to render.

You should also tell MyComponent whether or not it's supposed to show, regardless of it's children i.e. you should be passing `onEditable` to MyComponent by pre-computing the value, rather than passing the same information to children and back up to the parent.

This is called "lifting the state" which falls in line with fail-fast and early-return design pattern / best practices, and deterministic one-way data flow that React relies on (and tries to enforce).

---

Well, React works from the top-down, and parents actually specify props for children. I'm 99% sure you have everything backwards, and that you should be telling children `isVisible={true}` or `isVisible={false}` depending on `this.props.isEditable`. (or add classNames / don't actually render them).

The only way children can configure parents is via callbacks or through a global state manager like redux, which injects props back into the parent.

If your child is magically getting information about whether or not it should render, then it should call `this.props.onMagicallyGotSomeInformation`. Otherwise, the state should exist in the closest parent who knows this information, and it should be passed down / consumed where necessary.

Another critique is that short circuit operators and the syntax your using will cause you way more pain than it's worth. Use `const`, if statements, and curly brace blocks :) it will make your life easier in the long run.

HOC is a catchword, it's just an intermediary layer to determine which props should be consumed or forwarded to children, and I'd generally use `cloneElement` to customize children. Children should not have information like this, and if they do, you should get the information via callbacks.